# Code sample to use PowerUp feature

Tags: nodeos, eosjs, eosio-code

Can someone point me to code samples on how to use PowerUp feature? Also, how can a wallet be setup to use it automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line example that can be found [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/docs/04_guides/08_configure-use-powerup-resource-model.md#executing-an-order). A team of community members created a JS library that is worth [checking out](https://github.com/greymass/eosio-resources).

As for auto-powering up an account that is [a feature](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/562) that was requested and is being evaluated.